# Invalid handshake - arduino to nodejs server with socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, arduino, handshake

Me and my buddy are trying to push data from our arduino with wifi shield to our nodejs local server who's running socket.io (v1.3.4) framework and express (v4.12.0) framework.

We tried multiple libraries and we are close, but now we have an "invalid handshake" error when trying to upgrade our http connection to a websocket connection. Any ideas what we are doing wrong? Trying to connect with the echo.websocket.org service does work, so we assume there is something missing on serverside. (Everything is working fine when using chrome or other browsers)

**Node.js Server code:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    seats = [
        {id: 0, status: false},
        {id: 1, status: false},
        {id: 2, status: false},
        {id: 3, status: false},
        {id: 4, status: false},
        {id: 5, status: false},
        {id: 6, status: false},
        {id: 7, status: false},
        {id: 8, status: false},
        {id: 9, status: false},
        {id: 10, status: false},
        {id: 11, status: false},
        {id: 12, status: false},
        {id: 13, status: false},
        {id: 14, status: false},
        {id: 15, status: false}
    ]; //Seats from id 0 --> 15

server.listen(3000);

app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/');
});

// Socket code
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("Somebody connected, push seatlist");
    socket.emit('init-seats', seats);

    // Change status of zetel
    socket.on('zetel-toggle', function (data) {
        console.log("zetel-toggle called");
        seats[data.id].status = data.status;
        io.sockets.emit('change-status', data);
    });

    socket.on('hello', function() {
        console.log("Somebody said hallo");
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        console.log("Somebody DISconnected");
    });
});

/*io.use(function(socket, next) {
  var handshakeData = socket.request;
    for( variabele in handshakeData) {
        console.log("handshakedata: "+variabele);
    }
  next();
});*/
```

**Arduino code:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
// Here we define a maximum framelength to 64 bytes. Default is 256.
#define MAX_FRAME_LENGTH 64
// Define how many callback functions you have. Default is 1.
#define CALLBACK_FUNCTIONS 1
#include <WebSocketClient.h>

WiFiClient client;
WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
char ssid[] = "#####"; // Blanked out for stackoverflow
char pass[] = "#####"; // Blanked out for stackoverflow
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
int fsrReading;
int fsrAnalogPin = 1;
int LEDbrightness;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("Joining WiFi network..."));
  connectWifi();
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  // Connect to the websocket server
  if (client.connect("192.168.46.238", 3000)) {
  //if (client.connect("echo.websocket.org", 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  }

  // Handshake with the server
  webSocketClient.path = "/";
  webSocketClient.host = "192.168.46.238";

  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client)) {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Handshake failed."); 
  }
}

void loop() {
  String data;
  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrAnalogPin);
  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.println(fsrReading);  
  LEDbrightness = map(fsrReading, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(13, LEDbrightness);

  if (client.connected()) {

    data = webSocketClient.getData();

    if (data.length() > 0) {
      Serial.print("Received data: ");
      Serial.println(data);
    }

    // capture the value of analog 1, send it along
    pinMode(1, INPUT);
    data = String(LEDbrightness);
    if(LEDbrightness > 200) {
      webSocketClient.sendData("hello");
    } else {    
      webSocketClient.sendData("bye");
    }

  } else {

    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    while (1) {
      // Hang on disconnect.
    }
  }

  // Wait to fully let the client disconnect
  delay(500);
}

void connectWifi(void) {
  Serial.println("Attempting to connect to Y&RGroup-visitors using WPA2-Personal ...");
  status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  delay(5000); // give it at least 10 seconds to attempt a connection

  if(status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't establish a wireless connection.");
    Serial.println("Network capabilities have been disabled.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wireless connection established.");
    printWifiStatus();
  }  
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

When we run the arduino code this is what we get in the serial:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkyKk.png

Any input is welcome...
We're working on this for multiple days now without succes.
Thanks

Comment: any updates on that? did you manage to get it working or any alternatives?

Comment: The problem with socket.io and websocket client of arduino is that they are incompatible. 

Socket.io is a protocol on top of websockts, so it's not the same. You can't even connect a simple websocket client from javascript to a socket.io server.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the server listens for connection on the port 3000:

```
server.listen(3000);
```

But your client is trying to connect to port 80:

```
if (client.connect("192.168.46.238", 80)) {
```

Try this:

```
if (client.connect("192.168.46.238", 3000)) {
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste mistake from when we switched to the echo.websocket.org test... When we were trying to connect to our local server we used port 3000 - Changed in OP